# Kendo UI Treeview sprite goes away after drag&drop

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I'm trying to generate a Kendo UI treeview markup and make use of dragging and dropping nodes around. The problem is that after I drop a node onto another the sprite span element disappears.

Initial HTML markup:

```
<li>
   <span class='k-sprite'></span>
   <span class='node-text'>Node1</span>
</li>
```

And here's how a node looks like after dragging & dropping:

```
<li role="treeitem" class="k-item k-last" data-uid="054713f5-5ba3-444e-a322-72bf86d53ad5" aria-selected="true">
   <div class="k-bot">
     <span class="k-in k-state-selected">Node4</span>
   </div>
</li>
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BX4VC/

Any idea on how to help Kendo parse the HTML correctly so it preserves the elements inside the node after dragging them around?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is special handling of the `k-sprite` class, due to its relation to the `spriteCssClass` field of the treeview items. If you set an icon class, the spans will be persisted, as seen in the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BX4VC/1/).

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to add other data to the markup which will be parsed inside the node dataItem property? I want to be able to add in the markup the same properties which I'm using for the append() method.